# JavaScript - manipulate with a few ID of svg via one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a few SVG and each contains a few ID's. My goal is manipulate with the several ID's inside the SVG via one javascript variable. What I have tried, but doesn't works:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg"); //this ID has each SVG file and is loaded separately
    var svgElement = svg.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM .svg

var t10open = new Array();
            t10open.push(svgElement.getElementById("door-open-T10"));
            t10open.push(svgElement.getElementById("door-opened-big-right-T10"));
            t10open.push(svgElement.getElementById("door-opened-small-right-T10"));
            t10open.push(svgElement.getElementById("door-opened-big-left-T10"));
            t10open.push(svgElement.getElementById("door-opened-small-left-T10"));
```

in HTML I have checkbox with ID #T10 and here is the js function where I want to manipulate via one variable:

```
if ($("#T10").is(":checked")) {
t10open.setAttribute("display" , "visible");
}
```

**Unhandled Error: 't10open.setAttribute' is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

`t10open` refers to an array. Arrays don't have a `setAttribute` function.

If you want to set the attribute on each element *in* the array, use a loop. For instance:

```
t10open.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.setAttribute("display", "block"); // Note that "visible" is not a valid `display` value
});
```

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) talks about the variety of ways you can loop through arrays; the above is just one of them.

Answer (score -1):

thanx now it works (jQuery record):

```
if ($("#T10").is(":checked")) {
$.each(t10open, function(i,element) {
$(t10open).attr("display" , "none")});
}
```